# SLURM `srun` vs `sbatch` and their parameters

Tags: parallel-processing, scheduler, jobs, slurm, sbatch

I am trying to understand what the difference is between SLURM's [`srun`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html) and [`sbatch`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html) commands. I will be happy with a general explanation, rather than specific answers to the following questions, but here are some specific points of confusion that can be a starting point and give an idea of what I'm looking for.

According to the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/quickstart.html), `srun` is for submitting jobs, and `sbatch` is for submitting jobs for later execution, but the practical difference is unclear to me, and their behavior seems to be the same. For example, I have a cluster with 2 nodes, each with 2 CPUs. If I execute `srun testjob.sh &` 5x in a row, it will nicely queue up the fifth job until a CPU becomes available, as will executing `sbatch testjob.sh`.

To make the question more concrete, I think a good place to start might be: **What are some things that I can do with one that I cannot do with the other, and why?**

Many of the arguments to both commands are the same. The ones that seem the most relevant are `--ntasks`, `--nodes`, `--cpus-per-task`, `--ntasks-per-node`. **How are these related to each other, and how do they differ for `srun` vs `sbatch`?**

One particular difference is that `srun` will cause an error if `testjob.sh` does not have executable permission i.e. `chmod +x testjob.sh` whereas `sbatch` will happily run it. **What is happening "under the hood" that causes this to be the case?**

The documentation also mentions that `srun` is commonly used inside of `sbatch` scripts. This leads to the question: **How do they interact with each other, and what is the "canonical" usecase for each them? Specifically, would I ever use `srun` by itself?**

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The documentation says

```
srun is used to submit a job for execution in real time
```

while

```
sbatch is used to submit a job script for later execution.
```

They both accept practically the same set of parameters. The main difference is that `srun` is interactive and blocking (you get the result in your terminal and you cannot write other commands until it is finished), while `sbatch` is batch processing and non-blocking (results are written to a file and you can submit other commands right away).

If you use `srun` in the background with the `&` sign, then you remove the 'blocking' feature of `srun`, which becomes interactive but non-blocking. It is still interactive though, meaning that the output will clutter your terminal, and the `srun` processes are linked to your terminal. If you disconnect, you will loose control over them, or they might be killed (depending on whether they use  `stdout` or not basically). And they will be killed if the machine to which you connect to submit jobs is rebooted.

If you use `sbatch`, you submit your job and it is handled by Slurm ; you can disconnect, kill your terminal, etc. with no consequence. Your job is no longer linked to a running process.

> What are some things that I can do with one that I cannot do with the other, and why?

A feature that is available to `sbatch` and not to `srun` is [job arrays](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html). As `srun` can be used within an `sbatch` script, there is nothing that you cannot do with `sbatch`.

> How are these related to each other, and how do they differ for srun vs sbatch?

All the parameters `--ntasks`, `--nodes`, `--cpus-per-task`, `--ntasks-per-node` have the same meaning in both commands. That is true for nearly all parameters, with the notable exception of `--exclusive`.

> What is happening "under the hood" that causes this to be the case?

`srun` immediately executes the script on the remote host, while `sbatch` copies the script in an internal storage and then uploads it on the compute node when the job starts. You can check this by modifying your submission script after it has been submitted; changes will not be taken into account (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216228/after-submitting-a-m-batch-job-with-slurm-can-i-edit-my-m-file-without-changi)).

> How do they interact with each other, and what is the "canonical" use-case for each of them?

You typically use `sbatch` to submit a job and `srun` in the submission script to create job steps as Slurm calls them. `srun` is used to launch the processes. If your program is a parallel MPI program, `srun` takes care of creating all the MPI processes. If not, `srun` will run your program as many times as specified by the `--ntasks` option. There are many use cases depending on whether your program is paralleled or not, has a long-running time or not, is composed of a single executable or not, etc.  Unless otherwise specified, `srun` inherits by default the pertinent options of the `sbatch` or `salloc` which it runs under (from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slurm-devel/wKaUEOzuQq4)).

> Specifically, would I ever use srun by itself?

Other than for small tests, no. A common use is `srun --pty bash` to get a shell on a compute job.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is better than anything I could have hoped for. One follow-up, as this was one of my original points of confusion: why bother to call `srun` inside the submission script? Perhaps I'm confused about the meaning of a "job step." For example, if I have a script called `runjob.sh` that contains `#!/bin/bash srun myjob.sh`, is there a practical difference between calling (a) `sbatch runjob.sh` vs (b) `sbatch myjob.sh` vs (c) `srun myjob.sh` vs (d) `srun runjob.sh`? (Clearly the last one is silly, but I'm curious).

Comment: maybe you could browse the slides of a training session I delivered recently for ideas on how srun is used inside a submission script: http://www.cism.ucl.ac.be/Services/Formations/slurm/2016/slurm.pdf

Comment: It looks like all of the examples in the slides (as well as the tutorial on the CECI page) use `srun` inside of the `sbatch` submission script. However, I've found that commands without `srun` in the submission script will run the same way. Is there actually a difference between the four invocations I mentioned above?

Comment: All your examples will run the same way only if (1) the allocation is for one CPU and (2) the program is purely sequential. To see differences, request more than one task. Another difference is that if you do not use srun in sbatch, the sstat command will not return any useful information

Comment: How did you make slide 11, @damienfrancois? I mean, my `#SBATCH --argument` are not properly highlighted, and look like comments (in *Vim*). Do you have a custom theme?

Comment: @Atcold I use a custom Slurm syntax highlighting plugin: https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/tree/master/contribs/slurm_completion_help

Comment: @Atcold this version might more uptodate: https://github.com/damienfrancois/slurm-helper/blob/master/slurm.vim

Comment: @damienfrancois thanks, your presentation looks great! It's available through the Web Archive today: http://web.archive.org/web/20220505010613/https://www.cism.ucl.ac.be/Services/Formations/slurm/2016/slurm.pdf

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko thanks for your nice comment. You can fin an updated version here: https://indico.cism.ucl.ac.be/event/121/contributions/60/attachments/130/287/slurm2022.pdf

Answer (score 9):

This doesn't actually fully answer the question, but here is some more information I found that may be helpful for someone in the future:

---

From a [related thread I found](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slurm-devel/wKaUEOzuQq4) with a similar question:

> In a nutshell, sbatch and salloc allocate resources to the job, while srun launches parallel tasks across those resources.  When invoked within a job allocation, srun will launch parallel tasks across some or all of the allocated resources.  In that case, srun inherits by default the pertinent options of the sbatch or salloc which it runs under.  You can then (usually) provide srun different options which will override what it receives by default.  Each invocation of srun within a job is known as a job step.
>
> srun can also be invoked outside of a job allocation.  In that case, srun requests resources, and when those resources are granted, launches tasks across those resources as a single job and job step.
>
> There's a relatively new web page which goes into more detail regarding the -B and --exclusive options.
>
> doc/html/cpu_management.shtml

---

Additional information from the [SLURM FAQ](https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html#sbatch_srun) page.

> The srun command has two different modes of operation. First, if not run within an existing job (i.e. not within a Slurm job allocation created by salloc or sbatch), then it will create a job allocation and spawn an application. If run within an existing allocation, the srun command only spawns the application. For this question, we will only address the first mode of operation and compare creating a job allocation using the sbatch and srun commands.
>
> The srun command is designed for interactive use, with someone monitoring the output. The output of the application is seen as output of the srun command, typically at the user's terminal. The sbatch command is designed to submit a script for later execution and its output is written to a file. Command options used in the job allocation are almost identical. The most noticable difference in options is that the sbatch command supports the concept of job arrays, while srun does not. Another significant difference is in fault tolerance. Failures involving sbatch jobs typically result in the job being requeued and executed again, while failures involving srun typically result in an error message being generated with the expectation that the user will respond in an appropriate fashion.

---

Another relevant conversation [here](https://bugs.schedmd.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1634)