# SLURM - Launcher with and without SRUN

Tags: slurm

What is the difference between using `srun` inside the launcher script and not using it? for example, some launcher scripts are:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --time=0-00:05:00
#SBATCH -p batch
#SBATCH --qos=normal

srun pythonscript.py
```

but others change the last line directly to the script

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --time=0-00:05:00
#SBATCH -p batch
#SBATCH --qos=normal

./pythonscript.py
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `srun` command is used to execute a command/script on a cluster. It's an alternative to `sbatch`, which only submits the script, not executes it immediately. Both commands take a specification of where and how to execute: what queue, runtime, account, et cetera.

Using `srun` inside a script that was submitted with `sbatch` is somewhat pointless: when it's executed you are already on the allocated nodes, and then `srun` immediately executes the script. Which is the same as executing it without `srun`.

See also [SLURM `srun` vs `sbatch` and their parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767866/slurm-srun-vs-sbatch-and-their-parameters)

Comment: Using srun inside a script that was submitted with sbatch is not pointless. From [SLURM `srun` vs `sbatch` and their parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767866/slurm-srun-vs-sbatch-and-their-parameters): If your program is a parallel MPI program, srun takes care of creating all the MPI processes. If not, srun will run your program as many times as specified by the --ntasks option.